# Jquery close popup

Tags: jquery, popup

i'm trying to write jquery code, that will close simple popup. 
Here is example.

When i click on any image, popup is shown, but when i'm trying to close it, it doesn't work. I think it's becouse it's closing and showing again.

```js
$(".li").click(function() {
  $(".popup", this).show();
});

$(".popup").click(function() {
  $(".popup").hide();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>

<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>

<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>

<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `.popup` is within the `li` element, so when you click the `.popup` it gets hidden, but the click handler also immediately runs on the `li` to show it again.

To fix this, call `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the `.popup` click handler, like this:

```js
$(".li").click(function() {
  $(".popup", this).show();
});

$(".popup").click(function(e) { // receive the event parameter here
  e.stopPropagation(); // and stop the event bubbling up the DOM here
  $(".popup").hide();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>

<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>

<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>

<div class="li">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">POPUP</div>
</div>
```

Also note that your current code will close all open `.popup` elements. You may want to change `$('.popup').hide()` to `$(this).hide()` if you only want to close the clicked popup.

Comment: Great! Thank You. It works fine. Now i will try to make script, that hide popup, when clicked outside popup.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why there are two parameters "  $(".popup", this).show();" popup and this??

Comment: @Anonymous it's a [contextual selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context). Equivalent to `$(this).find('.popup')`

Comment: Rory - maybe You can help one more time. 
I have a form in the popup, but it's not sending (becouse of e.stopPropagation();). How can i make some exclusion for form?

Comment: The `stopPropagation()` call on the `.popup` div shouldn't affect the form submission. I'd suggest you start a new question about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks again :)
Why the form wasn't send? Becouse all of those images (div class="li") had parent form. That's why form-child didn't work.